# Jlink - including a directory that contains a custom python script in a JavaFX application

Tags: maven, javafx, jlink

I need to include a directory containing a python script and binaries that need to be executed by the script based on the parsed arguments in the JavaFX application.

The project is modular and built using Maven (although the modular part is not such an important piece of information).

When built using the maven run configuration, application works properly but for the purpose of creating a runtime image I stumble upon the problem of not having the script executed when I run the generated launcher .bat script in the "bin" folder of the "target".

For the purpose of generating the runtime, I have put the script directory in the project "resources" folder. The script is executed from the Java code using the Java Runtime.

Let's say the code looks like this:

```
pyPath = Paths.get("src/main/resources/script/main.py").toAbsolutePath().toString();
command = "python"+pyPath+args;
runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
process = runtime.exec(command);
```

And ***pom.xml*** file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>gui</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>gui</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
      <version>11.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
      <version>11.3.2</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
      <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
      <version>12.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.panteleyev</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <name>gui</name>
          <appVersion>1.0.0</appVersion>
          <vendor>1234</vendor>
          <destination>target/dist</destination>
          <module>com.example.gui/com.example.gui.Application</module>
          <runtimeImage>target/example-gui</runtimeImage>
          <winDirChooser>true</winDirChooser>
          <winPerUserInstall>true</winPerUserInstall>
          <winShortcut>true</winShortcut>
          <winMenuGroup>Applications</winMenuGroup>
          <icon>${project.basedir}/main/resources/img/icon.ico</icon>
          <javaOptions>
            <option>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</option>
          </javaOptions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>18</source>
          <target>18</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.example.gui/com.example.gui.Application</mainClass>
              <launcher>gui-launcher</launcher>
              <jlinkZipName>gui</jlinkZipName>
              <jlinkImageName>gui</jlinkImageName>
              <jlinkVerbose>true</jlinkVerbose>
              <noManPages>true</noManPages>
              <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
              <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
              <options>
                <option>--add-opens</option><option>javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-opens</option><option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-opens</option><option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-opens</option><option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-opens</option><option>javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-opens</option><option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-exports</option><option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-exports</option><option>javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-exports</option><option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-exports</option><option>javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-exports</option><option>javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
                <option>--add-exports</option><option>javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED</option>
              </options>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

***Note: additional options for the javafx-maven-plugin are added for the jfoenix package compatibility**

Also **module-info.java**

```
module com.example.gui {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires com.jfoenix;

    opens com.example.gui to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.gui;
}
```

Now the question is how do I include the script in the application runtime image, have it executed when I call the generated .bat for the application and finally packed using the jpackage?

Comment: If your Python script is an embedded resource, then I think you'll have to extract it to some location on the host computer first. I doubt Python can execute a script that's embedded in a JAR file or run-time image. This may be undesirable though. You might instead be able to make use of `--input` when invoking `jpackage`. I haven't been able to make that work with the class-path, nor by extension the `Class#getResource(String)` method. But `--input` ends up in the "app directory", and it seems you can get that directory by setting a system property (e.g., `--java-options "-Dapp.dir=$APPDIR"`)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I can assume that the $APPDIR could be related to the non-modular projects? I have followed the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/packaging-tool-user-guide.pdf)which states that for packing the modular application, module path can be specified using --module-path, while non-modular applications are specified with --input. Anyway, I have tried adding it as an option to no avail which is what I kind of anticipated going through the user guide in here. Do you perhaps have any more suggestions?

Comment: I added an answer to hopefully better describe what I meant in my comment. Note I thought of three possible solutions, but only the first one will work directly with `jlink` (or even pre-`jlink`). The other two solutions only work after packaging the application with `jpackage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problems

The `src/main/resources` directory only exists in your project sources. It does not exist in the build output, and it definitely does not exist in your deployment location. In other words, using:

```java
var pyPath = Paths.get("src/main/resources/script/main.py").toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

Will only work when your working directory is your project directory. It's also reading the "wrong" `main.py` resource, as the "correct" one will be in your `target` directory. Additionally, resources are **not** files. You must access resources using the resource-lookup API. For example:

```java
var pyPath = getClass().getResource("/script/main.py").toString();
```

And note `src/main/resources` is not included in the resource name.

### Executing the Script

But even after you correctly access the resource you still have a problem. Your script is a resource, which means it will be embedded in a JAR file or custom run-time image when deployed. I strongly doubt Python will know how to read and execute such a resource. This means you need to find a way to make the Python script a regular file on the host computer.

---

## Potential Solutions

I can think of at least three approaches that may solve the problems described above. As I only have Windows, I can't promise the below examples will work on other platforms, or otherwise be easily translated for other platforms.

My examples don't include JavaFX, as I don't believe that's necessary to demonstrate how to include a Python script that is executed at runtime.

Here are some common aspects between all solutions.

**module-info.java:**

```java
module com.example {}
```

**main.py:**

```python
print("Hello from Python!")
```

### 1. Extract the Script at Runtime

One approach is to extract the Python script to a known location on the host computer at runtime. This is likely the most versatile solution, as it doesn't depend much on the way you deploy your application (jar, jlink, jpackage, etc.).

This example extracts the script to a temporary file, but you can use another location, such as an application-specific directory under the user's home directory. You can also code it to extract only if not already extracted, or only once per application instance.

I think this is the solution I would use, at least to start with.

**Project structure:**

```
|   pom.xml
|
\---src
    \---main
        +---java
        |   |   module-info.java
        |   |
        |   \---com
        |       \---example
        |           \---app
        |                   Main.java
        |
        \---resources
            \---scripts
                    main.py
```

**Main.java:**

```java
package com.example.app;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path target = Files.createTempDirectory("sample-1.0").resolve("main.py");
    try {
      // extract resource to temp file
      try (InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/scripts/main.py")) {
        Files.copy(in, target);
      }

      String executable = "python";
      String script = target.toString();

      System.out.printf("COMMAND: %s %s%n", executable, script); // log command
      new ProcessBuilder(executable, script).inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    } finally {
      // cleanup for demo
      Files.deleteIfExists(target);
      Files.deleteIfExists(target.getParent());
    }
  }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>sample</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>18</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.example.app.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jlink</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>win</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.panteleyev</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jpackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <type>APP_IMAGE</type>
          <runtimeImage>${project.build.directory}/maven-jlink/classifiers/win</runtimeImage>
          <module>com.example/com.example.app.Main</module>
          <destination>${project.build.directory}/image</destination>
          <winConsole>true</winConsole>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Build the project with:

```
mvn package
```

And then execute the built application image:

```
> .\target\image\sample\sample.exe

COMMAND: python C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\sample-1.015076039373849618085\main.py
Hello from Python!
```

### 2. Place the Script in the "Application Directory"

*Disclaimer: I don't know if doing this is a smart or even supported approach.*

This solution makes use of `--input` to place the script in the "application directory" of the application image. You can then get a reference to this directory by setting a system property via `--java-options` and `$APPDIR`. Note I tried to get this to work with the class-path, so as to not need the `$APPDIR` system property, but everything I tried resulted in `Class#getResource(String)` returning `null`.

The application directory is the `app` directory shown in [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-DAE6A497-6E6F-4895-90CA-3C71AF052271).

As this solution places the Python script with the rest of the application image, which means it's placed in the installation location, you may be more likely to run into file permission issues.

Given the way I coded `Main.java`, this demo *must* be executed only after packaging with `jpackage`. I suspect there's a more robust way to implement this solution.

**Project structure:**

```
|   pom.xml
|
+---lib
|   \---scripts
|           main.py
|
\---src
    \---main
        \---java
            |   module-info.java
            |
            \---com
                \---example
                    \---app
                            Main.java
```

**Main.java:**

```java
package com.example.app;

import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String executable = "python";
    String script = Path.of(System.getProperty("app.dir"), "scripts", "main.py").toString();

    System.out.printf("COMMAND: %s %s%n", executable, script); // log command
    new ProcessBuilder(executable, script).inheritIO().start().waitFor();
  }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

(this is only the `<configuration>` of the `org.panteleyev:jpackage-maven-plugin` plugin, as everything else in the POM is unchanged from the first solution)

```xml
<configuration>
  <type>APP_IMAGE</type>
  <runtimeImage>${project.build.directory}/maven-jlink/classifiers/win</runtimeImage>
  <input>lib</input>
  <javaOptions>
    <javaOption>-Dapp.dir=$APPDIR</javaOption>
  </javaOptions>
  <module>com.example/com.example.app.Main</module>
  <destination>${project.build.directory}/image</destination>
  <winConsole>true</winConsole>
</configuration>
```

Build the project with:

```
mvn package
```

And then execute the built application image:

```
> .\target\image\sample\sample.exe

COMMAND: python C:\Users\***\Desktop\sample\target\image\sample\app\scripts\main.py
Hello from Python!
```

### 3. Add the Script as Additional "App Content"

*Disclaimer: Same as the disclaimer for the second solution.*

This would make use of the `--app-content` argument when invoking `jpackage`. Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to configure this using Maven, at least not with the `org.panteleyev:jpackage-maven-plugin` plugin. But essentially this solution would have been the same as the second solution above, but with `--input` removed and `--app-content lib/scripts` added. And a slight change to how the script `Path` is resolved in code.

The `--app-content` argument seems to put whatever directories/files are specified in the root of the generated application image. I'm not sure of a nice convenient way to get this directory, as the application image structure is slightly different depending on the platform. And as far as I can tell, there's no equivalent `$APPDIR` for the image's root directory.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested methods! Unfortunately I was unable to package the app using `mvn package` due to it informing me that the java:fx modules get treated as automatic by `jlink`. If I try running the `mvn compile javafx:jlink` to create the runtime image with the changed **pom.xml** configuration, I still cannot see the **lib** folder being packed into it with the corresponding scripts. Even making a small demo project that is considerably scaled down didn't produce the results that I expected. Perhaps there is a better way to package JavaFX applications besides the provided JDK tools

Comment: Were you unable to get the examples in my answer to work, or were you not able to apply the solutions to your real application (or both)? I forgot to mention—and I think I forgot that—I was using a JDK that included JavaFX (BellSoft Liberica). That may be why it worked for me (also note I wasn't using the JavaFX Maven plugin). I can see if I can get it to work using a non-JavaFX JDK plus that Maven plugin.

Comment: I have tried applying the suggested approaches to the both real application and the test application. Note that I was using OpenJFX plugins in IntelliJ, with code generated using the IntelliJ JavaFX generator. Either way I am using JDK 18 and OpenJFX 18 libraries which I forgot to mention, but I will try using the BellSoft Liberica JDK for this purpose again.

Comment: Sorry for the long hiatus, I managed to create the artifacts using the https://github.com/fvarrui/JavaPackager plugin for Maven which made the deployment a much easier task. Anyway thanks for the help!